# For this problem, a "word" is a string drawn from 26 options ab...z. n represents an arbitrary natural number.

Tags: combinatorics

For this problem, a "word" is a string drawn from 26 options ab...z. *n* represents an arbitrary natural number. How many words of length *n* are there, with exactly three *a*'s, appearing consecutively?

So exactly three *a*'s can appear in the word, and they must be consecutive.

My though process: the number of ways that *aaa* can appear is (*n* - 2)
and there are 25 choices for the other letter locations.

So $$(n-2)25^{(n-3)}$$ possible words?

Comment: Not clear on the condition.  Do you mean that the block $aaa$ occurs exactly once and no other $a$ appears?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. What approaches have you already tried?

Comment: I agree with the other comment, by the way.  This looks like a homework problem.  You should edit your post, first to clarify the question but also to indicate what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.  For example, can you do the count when, say, $n=4$ or $5$?  (I assume the answer is $0$ for $n<3$, $1$ for $n=3$).

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like routine homework problems and which show no effort.  Can you edit your post to clarify your question and to indicate what you have tried so far?  Like I suggested before, working a few cases of modest sized $n$ will certainly clarify the question and will probably give you a good idea of how to get the general solution.

Comment: question edited above!

Comment: That answer certainly looks correct.  To be clear, you are assuming (as I imagined) that the block $aaa$ occurs in the word and that no other $a$ does.  It's much harder to do the count if you allow words like $aaaba$.